# AD Security Groups not working with ADFS 3.0 on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, adfs

I'm working on configuring SharePoint 2013 to authenticate with ADFS 3.0.

I have SharePoint setup to use Windows NTLM for search to crawl and then have the site redirect to the ADFS login page `/_trust/default.aspx`

I've been working on fixing the up the people picker using [LDAPCP](http://ldapcp.codeplex.com/) to it will check against AD using ADFS authentication over windows. I have also set it up to find security groups by following the ["ADFS Not Resolving Active Directory Security Groups In SharePoint"](http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-security/adfs-not-resolving-active-directory-security-groups-in-sharepoint/) guide. The guide applies to SharePoint 2010, but the Claims configuration still apply to SharePoint 2013.

The issue I'm having now is that I can search for the AD Security Groups, but when I add them to SharePoint and grant them Permissions, none of the Users assigned to the group can access the site. Does anyone have recommendations to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I haven't tested it specifically, I believe it was the Jan or Feb 2016 CU will (attempt) to parse the group claim from ADFS into AD groups within SharePoint.

That said, what claim are you passing within ADFS? I usually use `Token Groups - Unqualified Names` to the `Role` claim. From within the LDAPCP configuration, you'll need to remove the prefix for the role claim as it puts one in place by default.

Comment: For Security Roles, I'm also using `Token Groups - Unqualified Names` to `Roles`.

EDIT: Do I edit the prefix in the UI?

Comment: It's likely an LDAPCP configuration, then. Take a look and see if you have the prefix for the role claim.

Comment: Thank you that what the issue, it the the `{fqdn}\` prefix in the configuration.